# Bootstrap 8 colums in a row on Desktop screens, but just 3 on mobile

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

I needed to create 8 columns (using Bootstrap 5) in a row for logos and did that like this:

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="row gy-3 px-5 pt-4">
          <div class="col-md-6 col-12">
            <div class="row gy-3">
              <div class="col-md-3 col-4">
                <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/500x300" alt="" class="w-100" />
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-3 col-4">
                <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/500x300" alt="" class="w-100" />
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-3 col-4">
                <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/500x300" alt="" class="w-100" />
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-3 col-4">
                <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/500x300" alt="" class="w-100" />
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-6 col-12">
            <div class="row gy-3">
              <div class="col-md-3 col-4">
                <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/500x300" alt="" class="w-100" />
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-3 col-4">
                <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/500x300" alt="" class="w-100" />
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-3 col-4">
                <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/500x300" alt="" class="w-100" />
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-3 col-4">
                <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/500x300" alt="" class="w-100" />
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
```

I now need to create a row with 3 columns for each logo for mobile devices. Basically, I guess I need to find a way to remove the second row for small devices. I have no idea how to do this.

Comment: It seems as if that behavior is already being demonstrated in your snippet. Do you want it to go from 8 directly to three?

Comment: @カメロン  I need to have 8 logos in a row show on big screen (desktop and laptop), 3 on mobile and 5 on tablet.

Answer (score 3):

You don't have to use two rows and cols. simply try it in one row and can change xs and sm depending on your screen size.

```html
<div class="row gy-3">
  <div class="col col-xs-4">
    1
  </div>
  <div class="col col-xs-4">
    2
  </div>
  <div class="col  col-xs-4">
    3
  </div>
  <div class="col  col-xs-4">
    4
  </div>
  <div class="col  col-xs-4">
    5
  </div>
  <div class="col  col-xs-4">
    6
  </div>
  <div class="col col-xs-4">
    7
  </div>
  <div class="col col-xs-4">
    8
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

change  to   it will work sm is used for small device like tab and col is for Extra small

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using [Breakpoints](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/layout/breakpoints/#available-breakpoints).

Use [Justify content](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/utilities/flex/#justify-content) for screens that are "medium" or larger and `col-sm-4` for "small" screens :

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="row justify-content-md-between">
  <div class="col-md-auto col-sm-4">Image 1</div>
  <div class="col-md-auto col-sm-4">Image 2</div>
  <div class="col-md-auto col-sm-4">Image 3</div>
  <div class="col-md-auto col-sm-4">Image 4</div>
  <div class="col-md-auto col-sm-4">Image 5</div>
  <div class="col-md-auto col-sm-4">Image 6</div>
  <div class="col-md-auto col-sm-4">Image 7</div>
  <div class="col-md-auto col-sm-4">Image 8</div>
</div>
```